# How to tell GraphQL requests apart in dev tools network tab when all have identical URL?

Tags: graphql, google-chrome-devtools, apollo

How to tell GraphQL requests apart in dev tools network tab when all have identical URL?

All my requests target `/api/graphql` so to tell them apart I need to click each one, switch to the "Headers" tab, scroll down to the "Request Payload" section and read the query. This means that I get almost no overview among the requests so I have to click several requests before I find the one I want to inspect.

How do people solve this?

Comment: Did you research for tools to help with this? E.g. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/graphql-network/igbmhmnkobkjalekgiehijefpkdemocm?hl=en-GB came up immediately.

Comment: I was thinking this could be solved in my code somehow so that it works in all browsers, maybe a util/library that adds a suffix to the URL or something like that. Installing a closed source Chrome extension is not an ideal solution for me.

Comment: Recommendations for a library would be off topic here. The GraphQL spec itself does not have specific requirements for transport, `POST /graphql` -> `200 OK` is a convention: https://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/. In general, if there are constraints around what *would* be an "ideal solution" they should be included in the question.

Comment: If instead of making the graphql request to "/graphql", I made the request to "/graphql/InsertOperationNameHere" then I would be able to tell the requests apart quite easily. Then I would have to write my server-side so that it listened to all "/graphql/*" URLs and just ignored the "/*" part of the URL. What perplexes me though, is that this seems like such a basic problem. Why doesn't everyone using GraphQL have this problem?

Answer (score 15):

Basically, if you're tired of this:
[image: devTools network graphql queries]

Use this [GraphQL Network Inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/graphql-network-inspector/ndlbedplllcgconngcnfmkadhokfaaln?hl=en-GB) to get this:
[image: GraphQL Network Inspector - list query with names]
[image: GraphQL Network Inspector - readable requests]
[image: GraphQL Network Inspector - readable + usable responses]

If the link breaks in the future, just search "chrome extensions GraphQL Network Inspector".

I know someone suggested this in the question's comment, but that URL is broken.

Also, I know the op specifically clarifies that they're looking for a in-code solution for all browsers in the comments, **but their original question is what I was looking for & this is my solution**. This answer will be useful for people looking for this, as this extension has really helped me!

It works for me because while I do test in multiple browsers, most of my development happens in chromium. This solution works for anyone who develops the same way and using a chromium-based browser (chrome, brave, edge, etc).

Comment: This is absolutely perfect!

Comment: I've just launched the desktop version of this app too. So you can now inspect traffic from any other browser. It's in early beta so let me know what you think! https://graphproxy.com

Comment: @wazzaday nice work - I'll check it out

Answer (score 7):

I'm using Apollo, and I found some info around this here:
https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-link/issues/264

The solution I went with was this query param (unused by server-side):

```js
const customFetch = (uri, options) => {
  const { operationName } = JSON.parse(options.body);
  return fetch(`${uri}/graphql?op=${operationName}`, options);
};

const link = createHttpLink({ fetch: customFetch });
```

This solution could easily be adapted to other gql client libraries.

Answer (score 6):

To use uri with a function to append operation name

```
const httpLink = createHttpLink({ uri: ({ operationName }) => {
    return `/graphql/${operationName}`;
} });
```

from: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-link/issues/264#issuecomment-461953427